# How to know number of tasks remaining based on a tag name in GAE pull queue

Tags: java, google-app-engine, pull-queue

I have a pull queue where I add tasks based on a tagname using java. The tag name is different for different group of tasks I add. Currently while leasing tasks from pull queue using groupbytag I am getting the tasks randomly but I need to know the count of remaining tasks in pull queue on that tagname.

Is it possible for me to know the number of tasks based on tag name?

Answer (score 0):

Tasks are stored in bigtable and thus are subject to the same features and limitations as your app data. You can think of it as if leasing was just a regular query, you can save your position and see if there's something else, but have no idea where it ends.

Counting and scaling don't go hand in hand. There are multiple ways to do it, with varying accuracy, cost and difficulty, so it's up to each of us to decide what's the most convenient implementation for our current problem.